# the windows phone emulator wasn't able to connect to the windows phone operating system

Tags: sdk, windows-phone-8-emulator

this message occurred when i run my APP

"the windows phone emulator wasn't able to connect to the windows phone operating system :

The phone didn't respond to the connect request .

some functionality may be disabled."

after searching i found this answer

"

Open Hyper-V Manager

Left column, left click on your computer name

Select Virtual Switch Manager

Select the Windows Phone Emulator Switch

Click on the remove button on the right side of the window.

launch the emulator

Accept the elevation of privilege asked

"

but message still appeared and my problem not solved

Hint:

Hyper V enabled

OS in my Laptop win 8.1 Enterprise (64-Bit)

Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate , Update 3

SDK 8

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: @Deepak yes create virtual Hyper-V whit name "windows phone Emulator" and and install in it SDK like virtual machine

Comment: AVG firewall was blocking the communication, so I turned it off and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

I also got this error message when I ran my app with the phone emulator:

> the windows phone emulator wasn't able to connect to the windows phone operating system :
>   The phone didn't respond to the connect request .
>   some functionality may be disabled.

This is what I did, which worked perfectly for me:

First make sure you have closed your Visual Studio and the phone emulator, then

- Open Hyper-V Manager
- Left column, left click on your computer name
- Select Virtual Switch Manager
- Select the Windows Phone Emulator Switch
- Choose Private Network and Click Apply

Then the trick is to restart your system and go through the same step above,
but this time:

- Choose Internal Network and Click Apply

Note : You'll see some Loading in progress,that's all , then start your phone Emulator Again

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and solved it by disabling firewall (AVG). Try this.

Answer (score 3):

do you have installed symantec? If so thats the issue. i am able to run only after disabling symantec. so you may choose to do so.

Regards,
Pankaj

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen and none of the solutions above helped unfortunately.
However, I noticed that in my actual network settings there were duplicate phone emulators. After disabling the duplicates that were unplugged my issue was solved.

control panel -> network and internet -> network sharing center -> change adapter settings: here is where you disable any duplicates you may have running for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

1. go to network and sharing center
2. go to change adapter setting
3. go to v Ethernet (internal Ethernet port windows phone emulator internal switch)
4. right click it and enable it(if already enabled then disable and enable it again).

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps and it solved my problem.

1. Move to “Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative
   Tools”, Here remove each and every Virtual Machines listen under.
2. Remove Hyper-V and then Restart the System.
3. After restarting, Install Hyper-V once again.
4. Open Visual Studio and Run any Windows Phone 8 app to start the
   emulator.
5. It will create again all needed Virtual Machines( you can notice
   from Hyper-V Manager tools)
6. While loading emulator, it will prompt for letting the emulator
   access the internet. say yes.
7. Let the emulator and your project fully load
8. Now you need to shutdown the emulator( by closing directly or use
   Shift + F5) and close the Visual Studio.
9. Now Open Network and Sharing Centre
10. Click change Adapter Settings (Listed on the left hand side)
11. Now you will see there - “Control Panel\Network and
     Internet\Network” Connections. some new adapter created by HyperV,
     they should be called “vEthernet(…)”
12. Here, You need to focus on the vEthernet( Virtual Switch) and
     vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal
     Switch)
13. Now right click on vEthernet( Virtual Switch) and click on the
     properties and navigate to the sharing tab.
14. Here, Choose Allow other Network users to connect and choose the
     vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal
     Switch) as the adapter and then save the changes and close Windows.
15. Everything work now.(Make sure your Wi-fi is working properly)

[Source](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.in/2014/04/how-to-solve-issues-of-internet-not.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's a firewall issue as above top 2 answers. I uncheck 'Enable Firewall' at Symantec Endpoint Protection > Network Threat Protection > Option. After the VM started, firewall can be turned back on.

Answer (score 0):

I noted that in my Device Manager I had a warning against Network adapters / "Hyper-V Virtual Switch Extension Adapter".

My resolution was to use Hyper V manager to remove the "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch":

1...Launch Hyper V Manager
2...Virtual Switch Manager
3...Under Virtual Switches list, select "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch" and click Remove
4...Refer back to Device Manager - the "Hyper-V Virtual Switch Extension Adapter" warning will have been removed
5...Create a new Virtual network switch (Internal), using the same name
6...You then need to open the Settings for each emulator and reconnect it's Network Adapter to the newly created internal switch
7...I also ran the Emulator repair (Control Panel / Program Features / right click Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators - ENU / Change / Repair) - not sure if this had any bearing on the fix
9...I then launched VS2013 and emulator now worked

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all guides above, nothing help.
Finally, I uninstall vmware player 12 and then it's work.
Hope this tip could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my AVG Antivirus firewall. The only thing needed was to disable **AVG network filter driver** in vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch) network.

You can find it in **Control panel -> network and internet -> network sharing center -> change adapter settings**. Right click vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch), select Properties, uncheck **AVG network filter driver**.

After that Visual Studio is able to connect Windows Phone Emulator.

Answer (score -1):

follow the following steps to solve this problem
1.go to network and sharing center
2.go to change adapter setting
3.go to v Ethernet (internal Ethernet port windows phone emulator internal switch)
4.right click it and enable it(if already enabled then disable and enable it again).