# Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator launches only from Hyper-V Manager

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

My Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise doesn't launch the emulator, however I am able to run it manually from the Hyper-V Manager. When run it from the VS after ~7-8 mins I get the following error:

"Windows Phone Emulator is unable to connect to the Windows Phone operating system:
The phone did not respond to the connect request.

Some functionality might be disabled"

What might cause this problem? I am running Windows 8.1 on Fujitsu LIFEBOOK E744

---

My case is slightly different than suggested duplicate as my notebook is in a corporate network and I am not able to turn off firewall nor stop any network monitoring software.

Comment: possible duplicate of [the windows phone emulator wasn't able to connect to the windows phone operating system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718897/the-windows-phone-emulator-wasnt-able-to-connect-to-the-windows-phone-operating)

Comment: have you checked the Virtual Switch Manager settings as suggested in the linked answer?

Comment: I did. Changed to private, rebooted and then changed to internal. Still the same

Comment: The solution for me was to run Control Panel -> Programs and features, select Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators - ENU, click Change and then Repair